# Resizing image without losing quality

Tags: php, image, image-processing

I have developed a site in [WordPress](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WordPress) using the Firebird theme. The slider image is going to squeeze in a smaller resolution.

Take a look at [this image](http://theme-dutch.com/presents/firebird/wp-content/uploads/2012/01/firebird-wp.jpg).

It is going to squeezing - see http://theme-dutch.com/presents/firebird/. Can we avoid it squeezing by resizing it dynamically? Is there a way to resize the image according to user resolution at run time, and is it a good practice or not?

Comment: Post the code where it places the image in the div.  Did you resize it?  I usually get it to work with only width at 100%

Comment: the code if you can on http://theme-dutch.com/presents/firebird/. because it have some dynamic values. slider is in <div class="sliderUL"> tag

Comment: The problem was with the theme slider. It was going to enlarge the image to more the 1900px. so the image was going to loss the quality. I have decrese the value which solve the problem almost.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with the theme slider. It was going to enlarge the image to more the 1900px. so the image was going to loss the quality. I have decrese the value which solve the problem almost